# MySQL Workbench INSERT INTO SELECT

Tags: select, insert, mysql-workbench

In MySQL Workbench I can put the following INSERT INTO SELECT statement into the query editor

```
INSERT INTO
  `tbl_texts` (`intBT_line_Id`)
SELECT
  `intL_Line_Id`
FROM
  `tbl_Lines`;
```

and it works,

How do I save as a query it in Workbench for reuse latter? It doesn't look as if I can, but is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can [save query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6DS3.png) as this way.

Files -> Save script As

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.